# Splitting column values into rows DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I'm using DB2 db for fetching data. I have scenerio like to fetch values from the database like this:

```
Select user, attributes 
From Data 
Order By DATE desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

Output:

```
user                 attributes 
------               ------------             
user1                Name=Rahul|Branch=CSE|Year of Joining=2017
```

I need to get splitted column of "attribute" into rows like below.

```
Name            Branch        Year of Joining  
-----           ------        ----------------
Rahul           CSE           2017
```

Could we achieve this in query? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

DB@ supports [`regexp_substr()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzscaregexp_substr.htm).  This allows you to do:

```
select regexp_substr(regexp_substr(attributes, '[^|]+', 1, 1), '[^=]+$', 1, 2) as name,
       regexp_substr(regexp_substr(attributes, '[^|]+', 1, 2), '[^=]+$', 1, 2) as branch,
       regexp_substr(regexp_substr(attributes, '[^|]+', 1, 3), '[^=]+$', 1, 2) as name
from t;
```